# Unable to get element value using javascript in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I am attempting to validate the radio inputs on a page, to ensure they are all filled in with javascript. The function works perfectly with all browsers I have tested on except safari. It is not reading the inputs from the radio elements.

When testing the function I simply count all inputs, when I return this value to test it returns zero on safari only.

The code is below, php, html and javascript.

```
//javascript code
function validate() {

    var y = 0;

    for (i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        var question = "question" + i;
         var x = document.getElementsByName('question');

         if(x>0)
         {
            y++;
         }
    }

    if (y < 5) {
        alert(y);
        return false;
    }


    <?php
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($this->question as $question){ 
    $question_number = 'question'.$count;?>
    <br><label><?php echo $question->question_name; ?></label>
    <div  align="left"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question_number; ?>" value="1"/>1</div><br>
    <div  align="left"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question_number; ?>" value="2"/>2</div><br>
    <div  align="left"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question_number; ?>" value="3"/>3</div><br>
    <div  align="left"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question_number; ?>" value="4"/>4</div><br>
    <div  align="left"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $question_number; ?>" value="5"/>5</div><br>
    <br><br>
    <?php
    $count++;
    } ?>
```

Comment: If your question is related to JavaScript, please show the rendered HTML, not the php (which is irrelevant, client-side).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You're better off using `document.querySelectorAll` and checking the length of the returned collection than counting elements one by one via a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out, your name selector     question   doesn't needed quote (string interpretation).

```
 var x = document.getElementsByName(question);
```

instead of

```
var x = document.getElementsByName('question');
```